# How to create a script to automatically duplicate a pre-existing tab on a google sheet at a specific time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script that will automatically create a duplicate of a pre-existing tab on a google sheet and hide the tab for the day before.
The original tab contains a lot of functions that import data from another sheet, I want the script to duplicate the data only without the formulas.

New tab name: Date of the day in this format ( 03/March/22 )

Cadence: Daily

Sheet ID: 1yEjCKwW7XPDNJfFaQcCAF23_B9P45xI9mwdOpFvrUP4

Tab Name: Sheet1

I've found the below script and it is working perfectly, but the only issue is it is copying the tab with all its functions, is there a way to just hard copy the data?

```
     function MasterX() {
  
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
 const patternX = '';
 
 var masterX = source.getSheetByName("");

 masterX.copyTo(source).setName(patternX+" " + getDates()[1]).showSheet();
  
 
  try{
 source.getSheetByName(patternX+" " + getDates()[0]).hideSheet();
  }
  catch(e){Logger.log("There are no yesterday's sheets")}
 
}

function getDates() {
 
  var today = new Date();
  
  var yesterday = new Date()
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1)
   
  var today_month = addZero(today.getMonth()+1)
  var today_day = addZero(today.getDate())
  var today_year = addZero(today.getFullYear())

  var yesterday_month = addZero(yesterday.getMonth()+1)
  var yesterday_day = addZero(yesterday.getDate())
  var yesterday_year = addZero(yesterday.getFullYear())

  var today_date = today_day.toString() + "/" + today_month.toString() + "/" + today_year.toString()
  var yesterday_date = yesterday_day.toString() + "/" + yesterday_month.toString() + "/" + yesterday_year.toString()
  
  return [yesterday_date,today_date]


}

function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Create timebased trigger to copy a sheet

```
function elfuncko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  sh.copyTo().ss;
}
```

Edit ssid and sheet name

The below trigger prevents you from creating multiple triggers for the same handlerFunction.

```
function creato_eltriggero(obj) {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "elfuncko").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("elfuncko").timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(hour).create();
  }
}
```

Edit hour and func name